# Как вывести отредактированный текст в TextBox

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Пользователь вводит текст в textbox, после нажатия на кнопку, из этого текста должны удалиться все слова , целиком составленные из вхождений не более чем двух букв и результат выведется в мою заданную область.

Однако у меня не получается, данный код все равно выводит текст без изменений, в чем может быть ошибка?

```
 private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            String^ line = textBox1->Text;
            String^ reg = R"((\w+))";
            array<String^>^ arrLines = Regex::Split(line, reg);


            List<String^>^ lines = gcnew List<String^>();


            label3->Text = "";
            for (int i(0); i < arrLines->Length; i++)

            {
                if (!Regex::IsMatch(arrLines[i], R"((\s+))") && arrLines[i]->Length > 2)




                    label3->Text += arrLines[i] + " ";

            }  
    }
```

Comment: А `arrLines->Length` чего содержит?

Comment: @NewView Length получает общее число элементов массива.

Comment: Так он какое значение имеет во время работы данного кода?